# Finite dimensional commutative local algebras -- reference request

Tags: commutative-algebra

What can be said about the structure of a finite dimensional, commutative, associative, unital local algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero?

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384902/classification-of-local-artin-commutative-rings-which-are-finite-over-an-algeb

Comment: That question is only about $0$-dimensional rings and it is still an open problem. This one is a bit harder.

Comment: You might want this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen_structure_theorem

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer by any means, but I might suggest reading up through Theorem 2.1 in this paper

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2012-364-09/S0002-9947-2012-05430-4/S0002-9947-2012-05430-4.pdf

Let's call our field $k$.  The upshot is that describing all of the $k$-algebras with the properties you list is equivalent, in some sense, to describing all of the submodules with finite $k$-dimension of a certain module over a power series ring.

Theorem 2.1 refines this notion a bit; it gives us an equivalent formulation of the problem of describing all of these $k$-algebras up to $k$-algebra isomorphism.